# Filter result of a Python Query

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, filtering

I'm  really noob on Python and i'm currently trying to get and filter the result of a get-iam-policy query on GCP by using this:

```
from pprint import pprint

from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

service = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

# REQUIRED: The resource for which the policy is being requested.
# See the operation documentation for the appropriate value for this field.
resource = 'my-resource'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

get_iam_policy_request_body = {
    # TODO: Add desired entries to the request body.
}

request = service.projects().getIamPolicy(resource=resource, body=get_iam_policy_request_body)
response = request.execute()
pprint(response)
```

It's working fine and i' getting this kind of result:

```
"version": 1,
  "etag": "VfRwfrGwlFjdc=",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "role": "roles/cloudasset.serviceAgent",
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:service-999999999999@gcp-sa-cloudasset.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      ]
    },
    {
      "role": "roles/cloudbuild.builds.builder",
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:999999999999@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com"
      ]
    },
    {
      "role": "roles/cloudbuild.serviceAgent",
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:service-999999999999@gcp-sa-cloudbuild.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      ]
    },
    {
      "role": "roles/cloudfunctions.serviceAgent",
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:service-999999999999@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      ]
    },
    {
      "role": "roles/cloudsql.client",
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:myproject-backup@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      ]
    },
    {
      "role": "roles/compute.serviceAgent",
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:service-999999999999@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      ]
    },
    {
      "role": "roles/container.serviceAgent",
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:service-999999999999@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      ]
    },
    {
      "role": "roles/containeranalysis.ServiceAgent",
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:service-999999999999@container-analysis.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      ]
    },
    {
      "role": "roles/containerscanning.ServiceAgent",
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:service-999999999999@gcp-sa-containerscanning.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      ]
    },
    {
      "role": "roles/containerthreatdetection.serviceAgent",
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:service-999999999999@gcp-sa-ktd-control.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      ]
    },
    {
      "role": "roles/editor",
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:999999999999-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
        "serviceAccount:999999999999@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com",
        "serviceAccount:myproject@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
        "serviceAccount:service-999999999999@containerregistry.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      ]
    },
    {
      "role": "roles/owner",
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:terraform@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        "user:myuser@acme.com"
      ]
    },
    {
      "role": "roles/servicenetworking.serviceAgent",
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:service-999999999999@service-networking.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      ]
    },
    {
      "role": "roles/websecurityscanner.serviceAgent",
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:service-999999999999@gcp-sa-websecurityscanner.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But I don't know how to to filtering for getting only the members of the "roles/owner" group. In my case:

```
{
    "role": "roles/owner",
    "members": [
        "serviceAccount:terraform@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        "user:myuser@acme.com"
      ]
    }
```

and put them into a variable for a later print or reuse

is somebody got an idea about how to do that ?

Have a nice day.

Comment: You can use [this API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/getIamPolicy)  to check it before using it in your python. Also you can use the [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/get-iam-policy).

Answer (score 0):

If you search IAM policy, I recommend you to use [Asset Inventory Search IAM policies](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-iam-policies). You can use it in command line like this:

```
gcloud asset search-all-iam-policies --query="policy: roles/owner"
```

And in your python code [like this](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-python)

```
from google.cloud import asset_v1

scope = 'projects/gbl-imt-homerider-basguillaueb'
query = 'policy: roles/owner'

client = asset_v1.AssetServiceClient()
response = client.search_all_iam_policies(scope,query=query)
for page in response.pages:
    for policy in page:
        print(policy)
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add below lines to your existing code:

```
roleList = response['bindings']

for role in roleList:
    for k, v in role.items():
        if v == "roles/owner":
            print(role)
```

Answer (score 0):

`response` is a dict which contains a key called `'bindings'`, which is a list of dicts. Dicts can be accessed with `[]` and lists can be filtered with `filter` from the python core library.

Putting that together, you could do:

```py
members = list(filter(lambda x: x['role'] == 'roles/owner', response['bindings']))[0]['members']
```